# animation css3 complete seen before delay

Tags: css, css-animations

Hello I have a problem with the startup of my css3 animation. It should be when entire rows end animation but when the index page loads I can see the rectangle appears, and then the animation begins. I do not understand. Can help me ? Thank you 
Here my https://jsfiddle.net/8y5b4u4z/

```css
.brand {
  width: 78%;
  font-family: 'brandon_text', sans-serif !important;
  color: white;
  height: 89%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  -webkit-animation: zoombrand 2s linear forwards;
}
.brandl .brand .titlesecond h2 {
  font-family: inherit;
  color: blanc;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-style: normal;
}
.line_top {
  width: 400px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-animation: line_top 3s ease-in forwards;
  -moz-animation: line_top 3s ease-in forwards;
  /* firefox*/
  -ms-animation: line_top 3s ease-in forwards;
  /*ie 9 */
  -o-animation: line_top 3s ease-in forwards;
  /*opera*/
  animation: line_top 3s ease-in forwards;
}
@-moz-keyframes line_top {
  from {
    width: 0px;
  }
  to {
    width: 400px;
    background-color: white;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes line_top {
  from {
    width: 0px;
  }
  to {
    width: 400px;
    background-color: white;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes line_top {
  from {
    width: 0px;
  }
  to {
    width: 400px;
    background-color: white;
  }
}
@keyframes line_top {
  from {
    width: 0px;
  }
  to {
    width: 400px;
    background-color: white;
  }
}
/*-----bottom ----------------------------------*/

.line_bottom {
  float: right;
  width: 400px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-animation: line_bottom 3s ease-in forwards;
  -moz-animation: line_bottom 3s ease-in forwards;
  -ms-animation: line_bottom 3s ease-in forwards;
  -o-animation: line_bottom 3s ease-in forwards;
  animation: line_bottom 3s ease-in forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes line_bottom {
  from {
    width: 0px;
  }
  to {
    width: 400px;
    background-color: white;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes line_bottom {
  from {
    width: 0px;
  }
  to {
    width: 400px;
    background-color: white;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes line_bottom {
  from {
    width: 0px;
  }
  to {
    width: 400px;
    background-color: white;
  }
}
/* ----------right -------------------*/

.line_right {
  float: right;
  width: 3px;
  height: 76px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-animation: line_right 3s ease-in forwards;
  -moz-animation: line_right 3s ease-in forwards;
  -ms-animation: line_right 3s ease-in forwards;
  -o-animation: line_right 3s ease-in forwards;
  animation: line_right 3s ease-in forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes line_right {
  0% {
    height: 0px;
    transform: translateY(0px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  /* retarder le depart */
  87% {
    height: 0px;
    transform: translateY(0px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  100% {
    height: 76px;
    transform: translateY(0px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}
/* --------------- left ----------------------*/

.line_left {
  float: left;
  width: 3px;
  height: 76px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-animation: line_left 3s ease-in forwards;
  -moz-animation: line_left 3s ease-in forwards;
  -ms-animation: line_left 3s ease-in forwards;
  -o-animation: line_left 3s ease-in forwards;
  animation: line_left 3s ease-in forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes line_left {
  0% {
    height: 0px;
    transform: translateY(76px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(76px);
  }
  87% {
    height: 0px;
    transform: translateY(76px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(76px);
  }
  100% {
    height: 76px;
    transform: translateY(0px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}
@-moz-webkit-keyframes line_left {
  0% {
    height: 0px;
    transform: translateY(76px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(76px);
  }
  87% {
    height: 0px;
    transform: translateY(76px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(76px);
  }
  100% {
    height: 76px;
    transform: translateY(0px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}
@-o-keyframes line_left {
  0% {
    height: 0px;
    transform: translateY(76px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(76px);
  }
  87% {
    height: 0px;
    transform: translateY(76px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(76px);
  }
  100% {
    height: 76px;
    transform: translateY(0px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="bannere">
  <div class="line_right_div">
    <div class="line_right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="line_left_div">
    <div class="line_left"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="line_top_container">
    <div class="line_top"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="brandl">
    <h2>WANA GROUP</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="line_bottom_container">
    <div class="line_bottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your start height is for `.line_right` is `76px`. Your start state should be `0px` and ends at `76px` so you want `.line_right {height: 0px;}` the key frame will change it to `76px` when it reaches 100%

Comment: Rather than posting a link to your website - which may change over time - could you possibly create a JSFiddle or CodePen with your issue? This will help future visitors to see the exact problem you're having in an isolated place that won't change over time :)

Comment: Yes my [link](https://jsfiddle.net/8y5b4u4z/)  but you can see the problem here the animation start normally i don't understand @GeoffJames

Comment: Thanks @heysabbinah - could you perhaps include this link in your question, instead of the link to your website? Looking at the code, as Andrew has already pointed out - everything by default starts at it's full width/height etc. If you remove all the animations from the elements you will see this. You need to ensure that everything starts at "`0`", and let the animation do the work. My guess is that you would see the full size box for a split-second because the animation hadn't started just yet. Hope you can get it sorted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set declared .line_ class heights or widths to 0 and then add your animations.

Comment: Set  `.line_top` and `.line_bottom` width to 0, and `.line_left` and `.line_right` height to 0

Comment: Thank you guys  @GeoffJames